# domain name and web domain have the same name, can't access the webpage

Tags: domain-name-system, domain

Hello our domain name is Example.com and our web domain is www.example.com, We have always had to put the www. before the domain to access the external webpage from our internal network, but now we cant access it at all. I have pinged the external ip and dns and it came back fine. i'm not sure what it could be. Has anyone ran into this situation before?

Comment: This is missing any sort of information that'd let us help you.

Comment: Yeah. That kind of happens when you let people set up active directory that never read the documentation. And thus actually - missing the basics - should not ask here but hire an administrator.

Answer (score 6):

I'm going to assume you're talking about an internal AD domain and your public web presence having an overlapping root namespace here.

This is because you've not followed Microsoft's best practice for naming your AD domain. You'll either have to

1. Live with it.
2. Run a web server on all of your domain controllers and redirect all HTTP requests for your external domain name to the external IP
3. Rename/migrate your AD to conform with Microsoft's published best practice of using an **unused** and **internal only** subdomain of your public namespace.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. Yes we have a AD server also acting as DHCP server. A different app server running IIS. It would allow for all internal traffic trying to hit the website to go through using www.example.com. Now for some reason will not allow anything to hit it. ping www.example.xom fine. also pinged the external ip for the website fine. Will not allow any browser to hit the external site.

Comment: @Vdub right. Because you need to duplicate your external DNS records internally because you've created split-horizon DNS. You set up your AD wrong and now it's causing you issues.

Comment: Yes the previous IT should not have made the internal domain and external web domain the same, I believe I have it narrowed down now to being corrupted files on our external web site. I changed the www. record address to an external and hit it fine. I will message back once I have fixed the issue.

Comment: It was our external web site servers firewall blocking our IP address. Thank you for your help.